# How to find Github forks of a deleted project?

Tags: git, github, git-fork

Recently there was an [interesting article](https://laravel-news.com/2016/05/echo-coming-laravel-5-3/) posted about a new feature in Laravel 5.3 called `echo` wherein it provided a [demo video on Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/lessons/introducing-laravel-echo) and cited a [Github repository](https://github.com/taylorotwell/echo-demo).

Unfortunately the original repository was deleted. Luckily I was able to search and locate a [fork](https://github.com/XristMisyris/echo-demo) made before the deletion. You can see there were actually 27 forks made, but none of the others turned up in my searches probably because of the generic name.

[image: screenshot of Github 27 forks icon]

Is there a more dependable way to discover forks of a deleted project than brute trial search?

Answer (score 5):

This search query on Google may help:

> "forked from {user-name}/{repo-name}" site:github.com

I tried it for a deleted repo with forks < 100 and got very precise 4 results and only those 4 results.

It still does not work for a deleted repo with only 1 fork I think.
At least it's another way to try.

Btw, you may want to remove the double quotes to get more results. However in my case they all point to the deleted repo so usually this may not be as helpful as you might think.

Answer (score 3):

if you know the number of forks you can search [based on the number of forks](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-repositories/#forks)

[image]

you can also search by date. also remember

> To include forks in the search results, you will need to add `fork:true`
>   or `fork:only` to your query.

EDIT: 
you can use this python script [find-fork.py](https://gist.github.com/akumria/3405534) made by akumria to help you find your desired fork

Comment: Thanks, this will be helpful if I was trying to track down a really popular repository that had lots of forks. I generally wouldn't know how many there were in advance for smaller projects, though. This probably wouldn't show at all if there was only one fork, and when the original was deleted, I'm guessing the fork would no longer display as a fork on Github.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can narrow your search a lot when scoping on language. E.g. using `echo-demo language:PHP` as a query in the GitHub search field.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is certainly helpful. But I am holding out for a definitive answer. It's possible that this functionality doesn't yet exist, but maybe some day it will and then we'll have an answer.